# Issue in incrementing index in array

Tags: java, arrays

> Question:
>
> You have an array of positive and negative integers, print all subsetsum which is equal to zero.

I have implemented only a simple test case here and the exception I get is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Please help why the value is not incremented.

```java
package app;

public class Array1
{       
    public static void subset(int p[])
    {
        int u = 0;
        int s[] = new int[p.length];
        if (p[0] < 0)
            for (int i=0;i<p.length;i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
                    int k = p[i] + p[j];
                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println(p[i]);
                        System.out.println(p[j]);
                        s[u] = p[i];
                        u++; // Why u value is not incremented?
                        System.out.println(s[u]);
                        s[u] = p[j];
                        u++; // Why u value is not incremented?
                        System.out.println(s[u]);
                    }
                }   
            }
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
            System.out.println(s[i]);
    }

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        subset(new int[] {-1, -2, -3, -4, 4, 3, 2, 1});
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not incremented?

Comment: When you step through your code in your debugger what do you see?

Comment: editing done.please see

Comment: @Jack , I highly recommend you read this (and generally about dynamic programming): http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `int s[]=new int[p.length];` as the number of pairs can be more that (input array length itself) is the reason you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You can use a dynamic list for this purpose:

```
List<Integer> s = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// s.add(<elem>); // no need for variable u - increment :)
```